# ICM: Malmuth-Harville Formula by Bill Chen 2

Tags: icm

There already is a question with answers about ICM: Malmuth-Harville Formula by Bill Chen at poker.stackexchange.com: [ICM: Malmuth-Harville Formula by Bill Chen](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9447/icm-malmuth-harville-formula-by-bill-chen)

I have no rights to comment it but I have a question. So I ask it here.
Both answerers operate with probabilities to win. The first has numbers:80, 17,3. The second one has numbers:50,30,20.

Where to take these values?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
It should be written: "Let's look at an example with player A holding 50% of remaining chips, player B 30% and player C 20%."